# While doing ranking on pig script giving error

Tags: apache-pig

I have below data in hdfs file :

```
(1,rohit1,CM,2014-12-31 13:10:23,2014-12-31 13:10:23,2015-02-02 23:23:45,9999-12-31 00:00:00)
(2,rohit2,GM,2014-12-28 14:20:23,2014-12-28 14:20:23,2015-02-02 23:23:45,9999-12-31 00:00:00)
(3,rohit3,CM,2014-12-27 17:40:53,2014-12-27 17:40:53,2015-02-02 23:23:45,9999-12-31 00:00:00)
(4,rohit4,CM,2015-01-20 16:30:26,2015-01-20 16:30:26,2015-02-02 23:23:45,9999-12-31 00:00:00)
(5,rohit5,CM,2015-01-22 14:20:25,2015-01-22 14:20:25,2015-02-02 23:23:45,9999-12-31 00:00:00)
(6,rohit6,GM,2015-01-24 14:20:34,2015-01-24 14:20:34,2015-02-02 23:23:45,9999-12-31 00:00:00)
(7,rohit7,CM,2015-01-25 11:50:58,2015-01-25 11:50:58,2015-02-02 23:23:45,9999-12-31 00:00:00)
(1,rohit1,KM,2014-12-21 13:10:23,2014-12-21 13:10:23,2015-02-01 13:23:45,9999-12-31 00:00:00)
(2,rohit9,GM,2014-12-21 14:20:23,2014-12-21 14:20:23,2015-02-01 13:23:45,9999-12-31 00:00:00)
```

I need to do ranking on records and want it to be partitioned by id and order by updated descending. For doing this I have grouped the data based on id as below:

```
load file data in A,

final_data_group = group A by id;

ranking_data = RANK final_data_group by updated desc;
```

But giving below error:

```
2015-02-03 16:21:37,555 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025:
<line 10, column 46> Invalid field projection. Projected field [updated] does not exist in schema: group:int,filter_high_date_records:bag{:tuple(id:int,name:chararray,margin_value:chararray,created:chararray,updated:chararray,start_date:chararray,end_date:chararray)}.
```

Can someone help me out to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is giving rank to the group, which is difficult with Pig built in function.

Ranking based on the projected field from Bag is not supported , only by the tuple file you will be able to Rank. In this case you can RANK by group field which would work.

[Pig - RANK Operation on Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239971/pig-rank-operation-on-groups?rq=1)

The above link explains how to RANK on group using datafu library